# Don't know how contains works to remove duplicates

Tags: c#, contains

Trying to see if a even number is already in my ListBox, if not I would like to add it.

I've had a look around but I'm getting confused. I tried using contains but I'm using invalid arguments, how do I tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void sortEven()
{
    string userInput = TextBox1.Text;
    string[] numberArray = userInput.Split(',');
    foreach (string i in numberArray)
    {
        int x = Int32.Parse(i);
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (!ListBox1.Items.Contains(i)) //error here, says invalid arguments
            {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

If there is a better/more efficient alternative to what I'm doing, then I would love to know that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to add `Distinct` even numbers in to your `ListBox`?

you could try

```
foreach (string i in numberArray.Distinct())
{
    int x = Int32.Parse(i);
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Windows Form then use:

```
 int iIndex = ListBox1.FindString(searchText);
```

If you are working in Asp.Net Web App:

```
 string crItem = ListBox1.Items.FindByText(searchText);
```